# Is there an alternative to the chrome feature flag "CommandLineOnNonRooted" to test a TWA

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, twa

I am trying to use a TWA as explained in the original documentation (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa). I tried setting the chrome flag `Enable command line on non-rooted devices` to `Enable`, but Chrome is telling me after the relaunch that `You are using an unsupported feature flag: CommandLineOnNonRooted. Stability and security will suffer`. I tested this on two real Android phones, one on Android 10, one on 9. I also tested it with multiple emulator devices on different Android versions but I am getting the same error message.

Is there any other way to test that the URL bar is not visible in the TWA, without the verification on the website part?

Answer (score -1):

This feature is for debugging reasons. If you just want to test if the Url Bar is visible or not you do not have to enable this feature.

From the Link, getting Started with TWA:

Enable debug mode:

Open Chrome on the development device, navigate to chrome://flags, search for an item called Enable command line on non-rooted devices and change it to ENABLED and then restart the browser.

Next, on the Terminal application of your operating system, use the Android Debug Bridge (installed with Android Studio), and run the following command:

Comment: As I wrote in my question: I enabled the flag, but Chrome told me that it wasn't supported. That's why I need an alternative.

Comment: Im getting the same Message, if i enable the flag.Thats normal if you are debugging. So you want another possibility to debug your application? Am i right?

Comment: Yes but the message tells us that the feature is not working correctly. This can be noticed as the URL bar is still showing up. And yes, because of that I was searching for a different way to debug, but ultimately decided to just let it go. But I've left the question up because maybe someone can answer it someday and maybe someone else will encounter the same issue.

Comment: Okay im sorry that i've missunderstood the question. On my Application the Url is not showing, but the message is still their. But i have no idea if there are any other ways.